# React JS - Passing Props to Sub Component - Not working for everyone

Tags: reactjs

```
class MainComponent extends Component {
   ...

   let render = <SubComponent {...this.props} additional_prop={this.props.match.params.id}

}
```

The SubComponent is receiving all the props as well as additional_prop.
This additional property is sent to api server through axios. It is not working for everyone. For some people, the property is received as undefined. Is this the right way to share props?

Comment: I think the components which are directly rendered by the Routes will have access to the `match.params` whereas components rendered inside those components won't be able to access this props. Can you please share your routes? And the name of the components which are able to access the prop and components which are not.

Comment: What do you mean by not working for everyone